# How to make save as button disable in pdf viewer in browser?

Tags: java, javascript

How to make  save as button and print button disable in pdf viewer in browser?

Comment: The same way you would disable the end user's use of the `wget` command. That is, even if you manage to get rid of the PDF's save button, you are not preventing the viewer from keeping your document; there are many ways to save it without using the most convenient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast solution for this Araf, you should rather display the text in HTML form because otherwise, you'll either have to modify the Adobe plugin (which of course you cannot without their permission) or design your own.